# Music Url not play in react native sound

Tags: react-native, react-native-sound

I have facing an issues to play music url from react native sound i used Music url `https://www.jiosaavn.com/song/mere-ghar-ram-aaye-hain/AVsuXSBBQWQ` but when I try with
.mp3 url it's working fine

please help me

```
const refTemp = useRef(null);

refTemp.current = new Sound(
         "https://www.jiosaavn.com/song/mere-ghar-ram-aaye-hain/AVsuXSBBQWQ",
          null,
          (error, sound) => {
            if (error) {
              alert('error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
              return;
            }
            refTemp.current?.play(() => {
              refTemp?.current?.release();
            });
          },
        );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JioSaavn url is a web app url not actual audio url, that have in-build audio player uses audio streaming url, You can't use in place of audio file.

You can also use [JioSaavan Python API](https://github.com/cyberboysumanjay/JioSaavnAPI) to convert song url to mp3 url that is useful to you.